# How can I achieve this layout in CSS/HTML without scripting?

Tags: html, css

I have four blocks of content, and each can grow only in specific directions:

[image: Growth directions]

However, I also want C to wrap if B becomes taller than A:

[image: C wraps so B can take the vertical space]

I also can't put a fixed height on the container.

Is that possible in HTML/CSS without resorting to scripting? I only need to support IE10+, no other browsers, so it's OK to use `flex-box` and `grid`.

Stated otherwise: I want to minimize whitespace while still keeping A and C touching and keeping B to the right of A. The closest I've managed is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2hw3c6vo/2/), but it doesn't keep A and B together.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.A, .B, .C, .D {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* NARROW VERSION */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  /* WIDE VERSION */
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .A {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    order: 1;
  }

  .B {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    order: 2;
  }

  .C {
    width: auto;
    order: 3;
  }

  .D {
    width: 100%;
    order: 4;
  }

  .A, .B, .C, .D {
    background-color: teal;
    flex-basis: content;
    min-width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
    A
    <!--<br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>-->
  </div>
  <div class="C">
    C 
    <!--hutihnj tghut rnojhirothijrotiohijrthoifgob irbno tinorbofgb fghfgnfgnf -->
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    B
    <br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>f<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically though....NO since "grid" isn't supported by any borswer yet,

Comment: I've actually spent the last several hours trying to code this for myself.

Comment: @Paulie_D, can even `grid` do this? IE11 does support some of `grid` with prefixes.

Comment: Fair enough. Here's the best I've gotten so far: https://jsfiddle.net/2hw3c6vo/2/